# rpart rounding values

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I'm trying to plot a model called "fit" that I created using the rpart package.
My problem is that the number on the plot are being rounded.
For example, if I run

```
plot(fit)
text(fit)
```

I get the 11.75 value, which is the one I'm expecting because if I type fit, I can see:

```
    alcohol< 11.75 1661  77 Bad (0.953642384 0.046357616)
```

but If I do:

```
  prp(fit)
```

I get the "<12" bellow:

[image]

I'd like to use the prp method because it allows me to plot nicer trees, but how can I make it plot the correct value?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the significant digits displayed in `prp`, which defaults at 2. I think you are looking for 4 digits, in which case `prp(fit,  digits=4)` should do the trick for you.

Comment: how did I miss that on the help? haha thanks very much.